# Multiple UIButtons Not Showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Whenever I code one UIButton it shows up but when I code two one of them doesn't show up. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(respringPressed)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Respring Device" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(300,-25,250,250);
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30];
[self.view addSubview:button];

UIButton *safe = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self  action:@selector(safePressed)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Respring Device" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(200,100,250,250);
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30];
safe.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:safe];
```

Comment: Please put your code sample also..

Comment: In code either you are making copy of button instand of doing alloc and init again or setting its frame wrong.

Comment: ceoplin check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code it did not show second button.You added frame and other things for button only not for safe in second button coding.I changed and checked the code.Now it works fine.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(respringPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Respring Device" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(30,-25,250,250);
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30];
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[self.view addSubview:button];

UIButton *safe = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[safe addTarget:self  action:@selector(safePressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[safe setTitle:@"Respring Device" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
safe.frame = CGRectMake(20,300,250,250);
safe.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30];
safe.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:safe];
```

I run with simulator.It shows two buttons.Please see the below screenshots

[image]

Comment: I've already done that though, I've been changing up the coordinates all morning. Can't seem to get two buttons to show.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a mistake dude ! you used "Button" instead of "safe" try to modify your code and don't forget to change Y position of button to a positive value :

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(respringPressed)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Respring Device" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(300,30,250,250);
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30];
[self.view addSubview:button];

UIButton *safe = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[safe addTarget:self  action:@selector(safePressed)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[safe setTitle:@"Respring Device" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
safe.frame = CGRectMake(200,100,250,250);
safe.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30];
safe.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:safe];
```